# vimrc mapping problem; execute python script mapping not working from vimrc

Tags: python, dictionary, vim

grr.  I'm struggling with Vim's learning curve.
And trying to get a simple mapping in my vimrc to execute the current buffer's python script. 
The mapping is well-formed and works after I enter it into the command line in Vim. This is the mapping:


    `map <buffer> <S-e> :w<CR>:!usr/bin/env python % <CR>`

But it won't load from my vimrc :(  I'm using the basic .vimrc_sample with only this mapping appended.  What's weird is that I could get a different mapping working from the vimrc:

    `map <S-t> itest<Esc>`

This one works, but not the script executer?  What gives?
Ubuntu 10.10 Python 2.6 Vim 7.2

Help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you have something before `map`: `<buffer>` argument means that mapping is defined for current buffer only, so adding it to vimrc without something like `autocmd FileType python` before it is weird. Maybe it is the reason why it does not work: you somehow switch to another buffer before testing this mapping.

Some additional things to concern:

1. Never use `map` where can use `noremap` instead.
2. You probably don't want this mapping to be defined for visual (at least without `<C-u>` before `w`) and select modes, and definitely don't want it to be defined for operator-pending modes, so use `nnoremap`.
3. `<S-e>` and `E` are equivalent.
4. You can combine `w` and `!...` in one command using pipe symbol: `:w | !/usr/bin/env python %<CR>`.
5. You forgot slash before `usr`.

Comment: Thanks ZyX for the advice!  -will do.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus, Murphy's Law.
After searching for an answer for an hour, 1 min after posting this q I solved it. The problem was `<buffer>` in the mapping.
Removing it made the mapping work, thus:
    `nnoremap E w:<CR>:!python % <CR>`